# how to build react js server side jpx and use it on client side with a php server?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, server-side-rendering, react-server

I am quite new with React js and I'm pretty sure there are concepts that I am missing and fail to find the right answers to my questions.

So I have a simple php project running on nginx, I am wondering if I can somehow avoid using a webpack server or react js server to do server side rendering and instead compile the jsx code with some sort of a watcher to then be used on client side.

The reason for this is because I realised if I only add

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
```

in the head and use the babel watcher with

```
npx babel --watch <indir> --out-dir <outdir> --presets react-app/prod
```

then I am unable to use open source libraries, such as [react-easy-crop](https://github.com/ricardo-ch/react-easy-crop) since they are built for server side rendering.

long story shorter, is there a way for me to compile what server side rendering would do, and use it for client side rendering?

Comment: The usual workflow with React is to use a bundler such as Webpack, Snowpack, Vite, etc. to bundle the frontend code (React included), then serve the bundle as a static file on your server. The Webpack dev server is used for development only.

Comment: @AKX hmm, so the process would then be `npm run build` on react and then use webpack to create a `bundle.js` from the files inside the `/build` folder? Then include `bundle.js` at the end of the body?

Comment: Pretty much. See what eg. create-react-app does.